# Attached artifact not deployed to artifactory by jenkins

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, maven-plugin

I have a maven project standaloneHostBuilder that creates a .zip file which I am trying to install using maven install plugin .

```
<!-- maven-install-plugin -->
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.3.1</version>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>install-zip</id>
<phase>install</phase>
<goals>
<goal>install-file</goal>
</goals>
<configuration>
<packaging>zip</packaging>
<artifactId>standalonehostrelease</artifactId>
<groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
<file>./deploy/sample.zip</file>
</configuration>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

When I build the project in jenkins the artifact is successfully installed in the .m2 but  the  artifact is deployed in the artifactory by the name of project's artifact id not by the name as I have given in the plugin configuration.
What I should do in order to deploy the artifact by the name as I have provided in the plugin configuration

Comment: install and deploy are different plugins.

Comment: Yes I was using maven deploy plugin to deploy the installed artifact to the artifactory. But I need to avoid deployment of an artifact in between my build .As the jenkins artifactory plugin deploys all the artifacts once the build is successful, I want that my custom artifact get also deployed to the artifactory. But Iam facing a situation where the artifact is deployed by project's artifact id name.

Comment: You only changed arifactId in install plugin.

Comment: Yeah I changed but the deployed artifact is deployed by the project's artifact id not by the id given in the plugin configuration.As my project artifact id is standaloneHostBuilder  but I want the custom artifact to be deployed with artifact id standalonehostrelease (as I have provided in the plugin config)